# How do I check if the inputstream from client side is an int data?

Tags: java, int, client-server, inputstream, outputstream

In my client-server program, the client should be able to send `string` and `int` value. The server will accept and do corresponding operation only when it is a `string`. Otherwise, if its an `int`, the server shouln't be able to handle it (or do nothing with it). How do I implement this logic inside an `if` statement.
I was trying with something like this, but `hasNextInt()` method shows error:

```
if(!incomingInput.hasNextInt){
//do nothing
}
```

This is the part where I am working in:

```
   if (msgFromClient != null && !msgFromClient.hasNextInt()) {
                    OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true);
                    String ansMsg = "Hello, " + msgFromClient;
                    pw.println(ansMsg);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've posted, it looks like you're just taking the value from the stream and parsing it as a string. If you take it as a string, you could call

```
Integer.parseInt(ansMsg);
```

Which will throw a NumberFormatException if the value is not an integer. At this point you can handle the exception as you like (by doing nothing). You'd need to use a `try catch` statement, but that's one way to go about it.

Comment: XtrmJosh, actually I just want to add a condition inside the if statement so that it says "if the msgFromClient is not null and also not an int, give the response back to the client". I hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   try{
      int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
      //if int
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

      return; //Do nothing.
 }
```